# chrome css bug text not breaking when running out of width

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, navigation

In chrome I am having a bug where text is not breaking on two lines when it reaches the full width of it's containing element.

Take a look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WJFH/) and you will see what I mean. The text is over the hanging the sub nav, of marketing services, where as in FF the longer nav titles are breaking onto too lines.

Comment: Can you give us a more simplified example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link's width is bigger than the list item's. That's why text seems to break out of the dropdown menu.

```
#primary-nav ul ul li {
    width: 105px;
}

#primary-nav ul ul li a {
    width: 135px;
}
```

If you reduce it to the same size as the `li` (or specify 100%), it works.